# Distance of different points on a list

Tags: python

Hello I am new to python,

I was trying to find the distance from different points.
Example:

The distance between each door is about 2.5 feet. So the distance between door 1 and door 2 is 2.5 feet. How would i go about looking for two different distanced in the door dictionary. or should i use something else.

```
d = {"door 1" : 2.5,"door 2" :2.5 , "door 3" : 2.5, "door 4": 2.5}

x = raw_input()
y = raw_input()
tol = 0


if x not in list and y not in list:
        print 'not a door'

else:
    if x in list and y in list:
        tol = (list[x]) + (list[y])
        print tol
```

Comment: What is the error in the given code? `list` is a builtin and it does not work that way

Comment: If all the doors are in order, in a straight line, and the distance between each pair of adjacent doors is the same value, then you don't need a `dict` or `list` for this: you can use a simple formula.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. So what type of formula is best for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following approach. This assumes all of your doors are spaced 2.5 apart and are in a straight line:

```
valid_doors = {"door 1" : 1.0, "door 2" : 2.0, "door 3" : 3.0, "door 4": 4.0}

x = raw_input("Enter first door: ")
y = raw_input("Enter second door: ")

if x in valid_doors and y in valid_doors:
    print abs(valid_doors[x] - valid_doors[y]) * 2.5
else:
    print 'not a door'
```

This would give you the following kind of outputs:

```
Enter first door: door 1
Enter second door: door 2
2.5

Enter first door: door 4
Enter second door: door 2
5.0
```

Or, slightly more Pythonic, you could learn about exeception handling as follows:

```
valid_doors = {"door 1" : 1.0, "door 2" : 2.0, "door 3" : 3.0, "door 4": 4.0}

x = raw_input("Enter first door: ")
y = raw_input("Enter second door: ")

try:
    print abs(valid_doors[x] - valid_doors[y]) * 2.5
except KeyError:
    print 'not a door'
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, this was very helpful. Also thank you to everyone that responded to my post. A million thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would do that with a function. Here a sample one:

```
# FUNTION
def calDoorDistance(doorX, doorY):
    # Distance between doors
    distance = 2.5

    # Splits the input string by spaces
    # gets the last portion of it
    # and converts it to integers
    door_01_value = int(doorX.split(' ')[-1])
    door_02_value = int(doorY.split(' ')[-1])

    # Calculates the amount of doors in between
    # and multiplies it by the distance.
    # abs makes sure that the result is always positive
    return abs(door_01_value - door_02_value) * distance

    x = raw_input()  # Converts the input value into an integer
    y = raw_input()  # Converts the input value into an integer

print calDoorDistance(x, y)
```

Comment: Thanks DevilWarrior. That works great, but how would i make it that when someone types in the word "door 5" and "door 3" in the int(raw_input()), it will result in the distance. Is there a way to associate a phrase with a number. That's why in the beginning I tried the dictionary, but that didn't work.

Comment: @wallace you could split the input string then get the number part.

Comment: @wallace updated the code, this allows you to use "door" without being specified. Ex: "Door 1", "Red Door 7", "door 4", "The big door in the corner 8", etc.... Hope it helped.